# Is there any Hive SQL function to assess whether the field contain alphabets?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Here is my program, it is not working as Hive has limited regular expressions support, is there a similar function for Hive SQL to assess whether the column contains alphabet?

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS
SELECT *, 
case
        when **REGEXP_LIKE**(TRANSACTION_ID, '%[A-Z]%') then "PRODUCT A"
        else "PRODUCT B"
end as PRODUCT
FROM OLD_TABLE;
```

Comment: You could create a UDF for that

Comment: I am new to Hive SQL, other than creating a new UDF, is there a way to assess whether the column contains any alphabet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 when TRANSACTION_ID rlike '[A-Z]' then "PRODUCT A"
```

Or additionally the same characters in lowercase:

```
 when TRANSACTION_ID rlike '[a-zA-Z]' then "PRODUCT A"
```